# Acer Monitor - Webcam not working

Tags: drivers, monitors, camera

I have an Acer B277 monitor with an integrated webcam.
Even after connecting the HDMI cable, the webcam refuses to work. I dont see any separate drivers available from the Acer website for this. How do i get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the integrated webcam is not that "integrated" after all. It is like a separate entity latched onto the monitor and needs a separate cable apart from the HDMI cable for audio/video.

After connecting the additional USB Type B connector to the monitor, the webcam should spring to life without any additional drivers.